# How many people have been test subjects on the Sattelite of Love?

Tags: mystery-science-theater-3000

In [Mystery Science Theater 3000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mystery_Science_Theater_3000), how many different people (characters) have been test subjects (forced to watch cheesy movies) on the [Satellite of Love](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_of_Love_%28MST3K%29) throughout the show?

Comment: I didn't see it was **you** that asked the question, but as soon as I saw it, I thought "Well, I've been seeing someone around with a screen-name who might- OH! He answered it already." Nicely done, Art.

Comment: Don't forget Jonah.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order of appearance:

1. **Joel Robinson**
   Test subject between the pilot ([KTMA-00- The Green Slime](http://mst3k.wikia.com/wiki/The_Green_Slime)) and [S05E12- Mitchell](http://mst3k.wikia.com/wiki/Mitchell_%28episode%29).

   [image: It Stinks!]

   <sub>Joel Robinson as he appeared in [S03E03- Pod People](http://mst3k.wikia.com/wiki/Pod_People)</sub>
2. **Crow T. Robot**
   Test subject between [KTMA-01- Invaders from the Deep](http://mst3k.wikia.com/wiki/Invaders_from_the_Deep) and [S10E13- Diabolik](http://mst3k.wikia.com/wiki/Diabolik_%28episode%29).
   Joel was alone in the theater during the pilot so he wasn't technically a test subject at that point, though he did appear in the episode, unlike Tom Servo.

   [image: Crooooow!]

   <sub>Crow T. Robot as he appeared during the [Season 7 intro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z81W6o3N7zg)</sub>
3. **Tom Servo**
   Test Subject between [KTMA-02- Revenge of the Mysterons from Mars](http://mst3k.wikia.com/wiki/Revenge_of_the_Mysterons_from_Mars) and [S10E13- Diabolik](http://mst3k.wikia.com/wiki/Diabolik_%28episode%29).
   As mentioned above, Tom Servo didn't technically appear in the pilot episode, though a vaguely similar looking robot called "Beeper" did (in the host segments only):

   [image: Beeper]

   <sub>Beeper as seen in **The Green Slime**</sub>

   [Trace Beaulieu](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0064546/) who voiced and operated Crow T. Robot during the first 8 series did not appear in Invaders from the Deep, and instead [Josh Weinstein](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0918441/) (who voiced and operated Tom Servo for the first 2 seasons) played Crow T. Robot and therefore Tom Servo was absent, first appearing as a test subject the next episode:

   [image: No Servo]

   <sub>Tom Servo, absent from a [rare Invaders of the Deep clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Npx1H61An0)</sub>

   [image: Tom Servo]

   <sub>Tom Servo as he appeared in the Season 7 intro</sub>
4. **Gypsy**

   Sort of. Gypsy joined Joel & The Bots in the theater for [S04E12- Hercules And The Captive Women](http://mst3k.wikia.com/wiki/Hercules_and_the_Captive_Women), though she got bored and left after 5 minutes:

   [image: Maybe Gypsy is the captive woman]

   <sub>Gypsy shown at the left of the theater during Hercules And The Captive Women</sub>

   She was also shown in the theatre during the [KTMA season intro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wKvSfG_XYyU), though never during the episodes:

   [image: Old Gypsy]

   <sub>The original design for Gypsy shown in the theatre during the KTMA opening</sub>
5. **Timmy**
   In [S04E16- Fire Maidens of Outer Space](http://mst3k.wikia.com/wiki/Fire_Maidens_of_Outer_Space), Joel & The Bots are visisted by a strange creature apparently from Crow's imagination, it's an exact copy but black, and eventually he begins playing tricks on everyone. Several times he shows up in the theater to watch the movie and annoy the gang:

   [image: He doesn't have a beard]

   <sub>Timmy in Fire Maidens of Outer Space</sub>
6. **Mike Nelson**
   Test subject between [S05E13- The Brain That Wouldn't Die](http://mst3k.wikia.com/wiki/The_Brain_That_Wouldn%27t_Die) and [S10E13- Diabolik](http://mst3k.wikia.com/wiki/Diabolik_%28episode%29).

   [image: Their experiments needed a good test case]

   <sub>Mike as he appeared in the [season 5 intro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=puFHjs9YaOY)</sub>
7. **Mirror Universe Clayton Forrester**
8. **Mirror Universe TV's Frank**
   In [S06E11- Last of the Wild Horses](http://mst3k.wikia.com/wiki/Last_of_the_Wild_Horses), the Mads perform a matter transfer experiment which winds up with Mike & The Bots in a Mirror Universe, where Captain Mike and Yeoman Crow are forcing Clayton Forrester and TV's Frank to watch bad movies, and the first third of the episode features them riffing the movie:

   [image: Last of the wild horses]

   <sub>Clayton Forrester and TV's Frank watching Last of the Wild Horses</sub>
9. **Eddie Nelson**
   In [S08E21- Time Chasers](http://mst3k.wikia.com/wiki/Time_Chasers), to fit in with the storyline of the movie, Crow goes back in time and tries to warn Mike not to take the job at [Deep 13](http://mst3k.wikia.com/wiki/Deep_13) which will lead to him getting marooned in space. Upon his return, Crow discovers that all that's changed is now instead of Mike Nelson, they've got his foul-mouthed, beer-swilling asshole brother, Eddie Nelson who riffs the middle third of the film:

   [image: You can't smoke in here!]

   <sub>Eddie Nelson in Time Chasers</sub>
10. **Pearl Forrester**
    The final test subject was Pearl Forrester, in [S09E13- Quest of the Delta Knights](http://mst3k.wikia.com/wiki/Quest_of_the_Delta_Knights) she's disappointed that she's been showing Mike terrible movies for 2 years with no real results, so they switch places and Pearl watches the first third of the movie with them to try and work out how best to torment him in the future:

    [image: This movie sucked]

    <sub>Pearl Forrester in Quest of the Delta Knights</sub>

So all together, there were **10** different test subjects. There were also a couple of visitors to the theater who didn't actually *watch* any part of the movie:

1. **Fred "Eggs" Eggleston**
   After Pearl has finished her investigation of the theater, she brings in "Eggs" from Facilitech  to fix the *Pain Leakage* which has stopped Mike & The Bots from experiencing the Deep Hurting Pearl desires from these movies:

   [image: Please call him eggs]

   <sub>Fred "Eggs" Eggleston in Quest of the Delta Knights</sub>
2. **Giant Servo**
   At the end of [S10E04- Future War](http://mst3k.wikia.com/wiki/Future_War), Mike starts making some shadow-puppets, and out of the blue a giant Servo shadow appears, which is turns out isn't being cast by Mike or Servo:

   [image: Rawr!]

   <sub>Giant Tom Servo in Future War</sub>

Comment: Just as a footnote, Fred "Eggs" Eggleston was also in the theater during Pearl's episode (*Delta Knights*), and another Servo was in there during the end of [S10E04 - Future War](http://mst3k.wikia.com/wiki/Future_War). Just wanted to mention these inclusions since Pearl and Gypsy were there by choice, and not necessarily "subjects." It'd be nice to have a more complete list of everyone who's been in the Shadowrama.

Comment: @MeatTrademark Great point, I'll edit those in, and you just reminded me of that episode where Dark Crow (Timmy) shows up, he's briefly in the theater too.

Comment: I can't believe I forgot Timmy! Forgive me, Art.

Comment: @can-ned_food Thinking about it, Cambot must be filming the movies, as he/she/it goes through all the doors into the cinema at movie sign, then reverses out for the host segments, though I couldn't circle him on the show to prove this.

Comment: @CrowTRobot Well, you were there; so, if you aren't certain, then it's hopeless.

Comment: @can-ned_food Joel restricted the motion of my neck motor after he finished mopping up the evidence of my first Exorcist impression, and it's really dark in there, ya know!

Comment: Are you going to update for Jonah Heston, etc. (I've been slowly watching so they don't go too soon. Hence, not sure if anyone but him and the Bots were in the theater.)

Comment: @MeatTrademark I'm not sure, I haven't seen the new show, can it even be the same SoL? It broke up and crashed on Earth.